# Task parallel library application crash issue

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am facing application crash issue on some machines and in the event viewer i can see the followign error.

*The process was terminated due to uhhandled exception, AggregateException*

**I am doing the following**

Starting a task to continuously poll for IE windows. This code looks for a window object using the window class and the title (using native win32 api).

```
public static CancellationTokenSource HandlePopup(
    this HostedControlBase control, string className, string caption,
    int? milliSecondsWaitBeforeAction, Action<IntPtr> onSuccessCallBackAction)
{
    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    IntPtr outputWindowPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    var controlLocal = control; //// for thread safety.
    try
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => Thread.Sleep(milliSecondsWaitBeforeAction ?? 0),
        cancellation.Token,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(
            (prevTask) =>
            {
                var condition =
                    new AndCondition(
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, className),
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, caption));

                AutomationElementCollection collection = null;
                if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    cancellation.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    return;
                }

                do
                {
                    if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        cancellation.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        return;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        collection = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condition);
                        if (collection.Count <= 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        outputWindowPtr =
                            new IntPtr(
                                collection[0].Current.NativeWindowHandle);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (ElementNotAvailableException)
                    {
                    }
                }
                while (true);
            },
            cancellation.Token,
            TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
            TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(
                (prevTask) =>
                {
                    if (!prevTask.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        ////if (outputWindowPtr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                        ////{
                        ////    return;
                        ////}

                        if (controlLocal.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            controlLocal.Invoke(onSuccessCallBackAction, outputWindowPtr);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            onSuccessCallBackAction(outputWindowPtr);
                        }
                    }
                },
                cancellation.Token,
                TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
                TaskScheduler.Default);

        ////t.Wait(cancellation.Token);

        return cancellation;
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        ex.Handle(exnew => true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

HostedControlBase is a Winforms user control, this code first sleeps for a few seconds (if specified) and then goes on searching the window using it's title and window class name. if the window is found, it calls a callback function which cancells the task using the "CancellationTokenSource" returned by the method.

**The big question**

Is this the right way of doing what i'm trying to do? Do you experts see any flaw here, My application is getting TERMINATED on some specific machines.

Comment: You probably should be using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` instead of `TaskScheduler.Default` for `ContinueWith`. Also, are you limited to .NET 4.0 and VS2010?

Comment: @Noseratio AFAIK  'TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSync..' will execute it on UI thread which I can't do. and yes, I'm limited to .NET 4.0.

Comment: It will execute the *continuation* on the UI thread, but not *the task action*, which still uses `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: To properly debug this, you need to figure out what exception you're getting (including its message, inner exceptions, stack trace). Without that, it will be very hard to help you.